# Is a crontab enough to schedule a celery task to run periodically?

Tags: celery

I have a periodic task that uses a crontab to run every day at 1:01 AM using

> run_every = crontab(hour=1, minute=1)

Once I get my server up and running, is that enough to trigger the task to run once a day?  Or do I also need to use a database scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It should be enough as Celery beat has own state file that is enough to run everything as you require.